# Improve "Questions that may already have your answer" section

Tags: feature-request

It sucks because:

- fonts are too small **
- I need to scroll using the mouse
- it's just a hassle the way it's implemented
- somehow it doesn't really give good suggestions because my answers often get marked as duplicate and it's not by one of questions in the suggested list
- it's unclear how is `Questions that may already have your answer` different form `Similar Questions` (isn't this just a duplicate? DRY your webpage)

I suggest `Similar Questions` and `Questions that may already have your answer` should be grouped in one place. Side bar is better idea than scrollable aread on top of question.

Sidebar `Similar Questions` is too narrow and red colored text is unreadable, especially on yellow background. Also line spacing should be increased to improve readability.

** Font is same size as related - perhaps, but line spacing is good in related and too crowded in Sidebar `Similar Questions` and `Questions that may already have your answer`. Readability is not determined by one factor, but combination of several factors (font size, color, contrast, line spacing etc)

Comment: Just a headsup as to a potential reason for downvotes here: if you let even a whiff of a rant in your post, normally you'll get at least a couple of downvotes just for that....

Comment: *it's just a hassle the way it's implemented* is a bit more than "a whiff"...

Comment: But it is a hassle because it's very hard to read due to fonts and scrolling necessary. 5% of screen real estate is used for job that needs way more

Comment: Anyway anyone is free to downvote, I don't care about my reputation here, but being able to use the site without hassle.

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš Meta doesn't affect reputation.

Comment: @Marko, how would you react if I were to tell you it's a hassle to read your question, with all the unconstructive ranting and condescending advice?

Comment: I'd be curios to know what you percieve as condenscending advice?

Comment: @Marko, *DRY your webpage* (whatever that means), *side bar is better idea than scrollable aread on top of question* (why?), *readability is not determined by one factor* (really?). Granted, they probably look condescending to me because you do not provide any rationale behind those.

Comment: DRY is common accronim that any code knows - don't repeat yourself. Readability is not determined by one factor was edit after I felt it was necessary to mention it because of the answer, which was upvoted multiple times.

Comment: @Marko, yup, I thought so. So what does *don't repeat yourself your webpage* mean?

Comment: Oh and @MarkoAvlijaš i'll point out the ironyin your first meta question today being 'plz comment your downvotes'. Yet here when we explain it you say you don't care. (Does that help maybe explain why people DON'T explaintheir comments? You ask, I deliver... You don't care. Will this really encourage me to continue posting these things?)

Comment: Yes because it's explained why - people are perceiving this as rant. @FrédéricHamidi I have edited the question.

Comment: So... You want to know, but when someone tells you you dont care? Again... Why should that behavior encourage me to explain my downvotes?if i don't i'm mean. If i do you don't care. I'll save some time inthe future by not explaining.

Comment: I don't care because I don't percieve my question as a rant so I don't see how I can fix it. Using words like hassle or it sucks is not a rant according to my criteria. Last sentence could be ineterpreted as rant and added no value so I have edited it out. But thank you for pointing it out, that was useful.

Comment: Really? There is NO editorial context here? The full question respects the 'be nice' policy? All in all, it comes down to : if you ask for reason somewhere you care. You can disagree with the reason. Doesnt mean you dont care. And yeah, does that highlight why people dont comments on downvotes? It's a catch 22 where the commenter either gets called mean, or gets into an argument. Given that choice, if it won't make you edit your post, why should people waste time explaining the votes? You want to know, but will argue any point made.

Comment: @Patrice Well, the problem, more specifically, is that people don't *constructively* argue the criticisms made, and tend to just dismiss them out of hand or attack the commenter personally for daring to provide feedback on the problem(s) with the post.  Constructively and politely explaining why the criticism doesn't apply or isn't a problem is of course appropriate and welcome by the sorts of people that take the time to explain their downvotes (or just comment on a problematic post in general).

Comment: @Servy 100% with you there. Just didn't feel like making the distinction as I don't see it applying here, but you are right.

Comment: @Patrice It was more for the OP, and other readers.  I didn't want them to misinterpret your comment as, "we're always right, don't argue, you're always wrong", when I know that's not what you meant.

Comment: @Patrice I don't really understand the "NO editorial context here" part? And yes I think this question doesn't violate "be nice" policy because it isn't mean to anyone. I do not see how I could make it less ranty at this point except maybe replacing words "it sucks" and "hassle" with longer latin words that obfuscate the real meaning. Frustration with design is part of feedback.

Comment: And what I meant by I don't care is that if SO users have an allergy to frustration or rant, it's their problem. I don't think this question was that ranty. Your feedback was valuable and thanks again.

Comment: Personally if my web design influenced some of site users to go into a rant, I'd listen very carefuly to what they have to say.

Comment: `somehow it doesn't really give good suggestions` -> Actually, my experience is exactly opposite; I've found that it gives *better* results than the regular Stack Overflow search! I don't know if it's technically different – perhaps it's simply because I'm phrasing my question and search terms differently – but I've often started to ask a question and found my answer in this box.

Answer (score 4):

> fonts are too small

It is the same font size of the "Related" list in the sidebar.

> I need to scroll using the mouse

You don't. Just click on an empty space within the list and scroll with the keyboard.

> it's just a hassle the way it's implemented

Why is it so?

> somehow it doesn't really give good suggestions because my answers often get marked as duplicate and it's not by one of questions in the suggested list

They could be better, and there is [real interest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286329/242059) in improving them. It is a hard problem, though, and it is not at all surprising that users with good knowledge of frequently asked questions in Stack Overflow can often do better than the automated suggestions.

> I suggest Similar Questions and Questions that may already have your answer should be grouped in one place. Side bar is better idea than scrollable aread on top of question.

Placing the "Questions that may..." list there would make it harder to notice for new users, which would be highly counterprouductive.

Comment: `Similar Questions` and related are not the same thing. `Similar Questions` appears on side after you enter question title and start entering questions body. It is present on the page at the same time as `Questions that may already have your answer`

Comment: Going to edit last 2 paragraphs

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš On Similar vs. Related: fair enough. I'm removing the irrelevant parts of my answer.

Comment: I have also editted my question regarding fonts